# Does the batch command "ren" cause write operations on disk?

Tags: batch-file, filesystems, ssd

### Problem statement

We are using a batch-script, part of which is using the `ren` command to rename a file. This script is ran once per second, possibly even at a higher frequency than that in the future.

I would like to make sure that this causes no excessive write-erase-operations on the SSD it is working on. If `ren` writes a new file, copies contents of the old one to memory, then writes the contents into the new file from memory and erases the old file, then `ren` would be executing write-erase-cycles on the SSD, which may shorten its lifespan (?). However if `ren` merely changes the pointer to the file, *i.e.*  changes name and location of the file without write-erase-operations on the SSD, then my worries are unfounded.

How does `ren` operate internally? Do I have to worry about the SSD lifespan being shortened when the aforementioned batch script is executing the `ren` command at a frequency of once per second or higher?

Comment: `Ren` doesn't change the location either! Anyhow, your question is not about the `ren` command, but more about renaming file and directory objects. IMO this is not a programming question but more about filesystems and hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ren command only changes a property of file. It is the file name which is metadata. There is no need to write file data to a different location upon renaming a file.

Unfortunately every slightest change, even changing a file name by one letter requires rewriting at least a block on your flash storage. That applies to hard disk drives as well where at least a sector has to be rewritten.

You can reduce this stress by using caching mechanisms but this wear savings  come at the cost of data loss in case of power outages.

Comment: Do you propose any specific caching mechanisms? Data loss is of no concern to me in this specific scenario.

Comment: The OS and the disk are already caching.  Plus caching caching will have little affect if the writes arent to the same block.  SSDs are very robust these days.   If you are writing so much that the health declines quickly, SSDs are not the proper storage medium for this process.

Comment: Koenigsberg, your statements are contradictory. If data loss is no concern, reduce the file renaming frequencing and save that information somewhere else. It appears to me as if you are abusing a file name as a variable in a program which is not a good idea. If you write data into a file you will profit from the caching methods of your operation system.